# Rename file in use by my application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've done a search and found a few similar threads to my own, though their fixes haven't really helped me.

I'm making an image management software and have the images opened in a file-explorer type of listview, then previewed in a picturebox on click. I wanted to have an option to rename the image file (e.g. if it's something like 234234234.jpg, rename it to something relevant like "trip with parents.jpg"). The problem is that the file is always in use by my application. I've tried disposing all the image objects as well as the controls using them, but nothing is working properly. I always get that IOException that the file is in use by another process (my program).

I'm using `File.Move` and have tried `My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile`.

My current code:

```
If BasePathWithItem = "" Then Exit Sub

File.Move(BasePathWithItem, BasePath & txtPicTitle.Text & txtExtension.Text)
PopulateImgList()
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm good with both VB and C# so help in either language is acceptable.

Thanks very much

Comment: How are you loading and displaying the images to begin with? It sounds like you're reading the graphics in a way that prevents them from closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap` objects keep open the stream from which they are created.  (See the "Remarks" section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)  One solution to your problem is to read the entire image file into a `MemoryStream` and then create the `Bitmap` from the `MemoryStream`.  Close the original `FileStream`, and you'll be able to move the file.